# How to output Simple Array Sum challenge of HackerRank in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I was just trying to get familiar with HackerRank environment and practice some problems.

I was attempting its 2nd challenge in Algorithms>Warmups:
[Simple Array Sum](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum)

I have solved it and its working fine on my local machine.

```
Code:
<?php

function testSum($n,$x)
{
   $sum=0;  
   $x =explode(" ",$x);
    for($i=0;i<$n;$i++)  
        {  
        $sum+=$x[$i];  
    }  
    echo $sum;
}
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$arr = explode(" ",$arr_temp);
array_walk($arr,'intval');

?>
```

But It keeps giving me same response every time:
[Response on running code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmuox.png)

Please help me how to print results in hackerrank and what am I missing here. Thanks

Comment: Did you select the programing language as a PHP? And tick `Test against custom input`.Hope it will be worked.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud yes i have selected PHP and the code I have pasted here includes the default environment code as well

Comment: You should tick `Test against custom input` and input some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the first one but let me try (mine works on hackerrank.com too :)

```
<?php
/* simple solution for https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum */

/* Read and parse input */
$handle = fopen ('php://stdin', 'r');
fscanf($handle, '%d', $n);
$numbers = explode(' ', fgets($handle));
array_walk($numbers, function (&$value) {
    $value = intval($value);
});

/* result: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php */
echo array_sum($numbers);
```

Simple step by step explanation

1. [Read user input](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) - check the examples in the documentation.
2. [`fscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) is really not needed here. In our case it reads number from input and stores the value in the `$n` variable. Check [format description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) in the docs.
3. [`fgets($handle)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgets.php) reads a string. Next we split the string into array using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). These are all very basic and often used PHP functions, make sure to get familiar with them and read the documentation.
4. We walk ([`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)) through the array and convert all elements to integers. We use [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php) in the example. This is a bit more advanced technique and might be skipped here.
5. Finally we calculate and output the sum using [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$arr = explode(" ",$arr_temp);
array_walk($arr,'intval');

 $sum = 0;
for($i = 0; $i< $n; $i++) {
        $sum = $sum + $arr[$i];
    }
fwrite(STDOUT, $sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just do this:**

```
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$arr = explode(" ",$arr_temp);

echo array_sum($arr);
```

Comment: can you write it in form of a complete solution? so, I can better understand its code order. thanks

Comment: This is a complete solution. I tried it in the hackerRank site. Just do it.